# HIdden characters in cytoscape names

Tags: filenames, cytoscape

I am attempting to upload a .cys file to a journal website as part of a submission.  Although they accept all file types, when I try to upload the .cys file, the name exceeds the 64-character limit, apparently due to some hidden characters in the name.  Is there anyway to see the hidden characters in the file name and/or change them so the filename is less than 64 characters?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply rename the .cys file, however, they might be attempting to unzip it automatically (a .cys file is actually just a zip archive of everything in a Cytoscape session), in which case, they might be having problems with some of the filenames inside of the .cys file, which can't be renamed.  You'll need to ask the journal about that.

-- scooter